# windows XP as ntp server can't reach

Tags: windows, testing, ntp

Tried with Configuration With Meinberg Radio Clock (Windows) and the ntp status return

*LOCAL<0>       .LOCL.     ...

REACH 77 so it's seems reachable, but if I setup a ntp client it can't reach this server...it ping, but it doesn't reach it.
What can it be?

I didn't get if by default MS XP can be a ntp server or not, by googling you can find how to setup a server, so this mean it run as a client for an exernal server.

Comment: Try all the trivial stuff and if all else fails post your config: did you open port 123? If you use a simple ntp client (google for any), can it reach the server from a client/the server itself? (edit: assuming you set it up to listen on localhost of course)

Comment: The client launched on the same host as the server, run and can reach the server, but from other machines no. Even if with a port scan the udp port seems open.

Comment: Well then, try setting up a fake ntp server (anything on port 123 udp that sends junk and prints a message when it receives a connection); if you can't reach it from the other computers you'll know it's a network problem, otherwise you should post your ntp config -- btw, there's a newsgroup for that

Answer (score 0):

Why not use samba?
It is already in windows.
Linux usually supports it out of the box

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I need to run windows on the server, I can't use linux(this time).

Comment: windows supports it as its default file sharing system